# Need to use VFP code to display PDF files in VFP Windows

Tags: pdf, visual-foxpro

Users running my Foxpro 9.0 app generate a lot of PDF files. I need to show PDF files in a window.  I installed Google Chrome and set it as the default for PDFs and when double clicking on a PDF in file explorer it comes right up in Chrome.  I need to make that happen with Foxpro code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use the ShellExecute API function, or the _ShellExecute class that comes with VFP and wraps the API function. Here's an article on how to use ShellExecute in VFP: http://www.ml-consult.co.uk/foxst-26.htm

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Tamar said:

```
declare long ShellExecute in "shell32.dll" ;
    long hwnd, string lpszOp, ;
    string lpszFile, string lpszParams, ;
    string lpszDir, long nShowCmd
ShellExecute(0,'Open','c:\MyFolder\MyFile.pdf','','',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  The ShellExecute works great.  However, it will not work when my VFP program is running in the Thinfinity web server. The fix is to convert the PDF to a JPG or PNG before saving them.  The PNG files take 1/3 the space of JPG files. I'm using PDFill with it's command line utility to convert them.

Comment: Good to know that I shouldn't use Thinfinity.

Comment: Cetin, I love Thinfinity.  It runs my 25 year old huge VFP management system without any changes.  It does have some limitations though but Its better than rewriting an app with over 350 screens.

Comment: I checked their site and didn't understand what I need for licensing. 25$ per user? Or 25$ per user + 80$? Or 80$ for user? What do I need if I have 100 users accessing the same application (80$ + 100 * 25$ ?). Also I didn't understand what it really provides for me? Usage on any platform? How is it different from say Chrome RDP.

Comment: Cybele has several products. Make sure you are looking at "Thinfinity VirtualUI". There are two licenses. The 1st is is Developer ($149). That covers the server and one user license. The other is User ($69). You need 1 for each simultaneous user on a server. That license is perpetual and covers all software Thinfinity is hosting on that server. Download the developer 30 day  trial. They have been very good about extending the demo with 10 users for me over several months! The initial VFP install is a bit tricky so please fell free to contact me for help.

Comment: Thank you. If I ever get into it, and cannot solve myself in a few hours I will do.